# How to import all images from a folder with Parcel JS

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I could spend an hour explaining my code and everything I've tried, but the absolute basics is this:

Onload, my script creates buttons for each `type` in the `types` array:

```js
for(let type of types) {
        let btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.innerHTML = `<img class="type-icon" src="img/types/${type.name}.svg"> `;
```

I have a folder called `img` with a folder called `types` inside it where I store 18 "type" icons, for "fire", "water", etc.

Is there a way of doing this dynamically with parcel JS?

---

Currently, the images are all missing. I've tried importing `*` but that doesn't seem to work with Parcel. I've tried requiring them dynamically, also doesn't work. I understand that Parcel probably looks through for the names of files to import and in the generated scripts replaces those names with the file names... Is there a way to do this with static assets? I had the same problem with my json files and it took me a while to figure out that I needed to remove all of my fetch code and import them. Is there a way to keep the same file names with Parcel? It doesn't seem like there is, but if it's not combining the files anyway I don't see why not...

Answer (score 1):

So I just came across the same problem today.
It's apparently a known issue: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1411

I used the linked plugin and it works fine: https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy

Add all your images in a folder named static and you can access them with the same names they have locally (without static in the uri).

Comment: For, this plugin not worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but you can fix it using parcel-plugin-static-files-copy package: [parcel-plugin-static-files-copy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy).
Then install by using this command
**npm i parcel-plugin-static-files-copy**
, then add this to your **.parcelrc** plagin

```
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "resolvers": ["@parcel/resolver-glob", "..."]
}
```

Once enabled, you can import multiple files using a specifier like **./files/*.png**. This returns an object with keys corresponding to the files names.

```
import * as images from './img/types/*.svg';
```